# Sketch 3 - Designing a symmetrical graphic

Tags: sketch-app

How do I create a symmertical copy of a graphic in Sketch 3.

In other words, how do I take a graphic and then mirror a copy of it over a specified line?

Additionally, is there a way for Sketch to keep the 2 objects "synced" at all times? In other words, when I change the dimensions of the origin, the mirror updates as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we want to mirror twitter icon png.

First, place two rules at 0:0 point it will be convenient to align mirror objects around them. Place your graphic :
[image]

Place rectangle under the graphic make it the same size as graphic, deselect **Fills** and **Borders** check boxes, right click on rect and select **Use as Mask**:
[image]

Select graphic and rect and click **Create Symbol** icon in the Tools panel, this will make possible to change scale of your original graphic and its copy in the same time:
[image]

Duplicate sybmol by pressing **Ctrl+D**, flip it horizontal and place against your original graphic:
[image]

Now, you can select on of the graphic inside symbol and move it right or left, the copy will move too:
[image]

If you want to change the size of graphics select symbol and press **Scale** icon:
[image]

Scaling your graphic will move your graphics from original point:
[image]

But you can adjust its positions by dragging them and anchor to the rulers:
[image]

That's my approach to solve your issue.
You can [**download**](http://ge.tt/5OvqmaZ2) sketch file with mirror graphics.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to illustrate the steps and provide a file download.

Answer (score 4):

To keep your objects synced you can use [symbols](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/07-symbols/). This is as simple as pressing the **Create Symbol** button in the toolbar with your artwork selected, then you can **Insert › Symbol** to insert a new instance of your symbol.

You can use the inspector panel to flip your symbol.

[image: inspector panel flip]

Comment: What is the different between this and the approach in the other answer? I accepted the other because its more along the lines of what I was expecting to do intuitively . Will your approach work for ANY arbitrary content? If you elaborate the difference pros/cons between the approaches I will award this answer an additional bounty.

Comment: There's no difference at all, they're exactly the same approach. I posted this first but the other answer goes in to more detail with screenshots etc so no need for additional bounties :)